# Rename branch to "master" without merging?

Tags: git

I have a single-developer app that was originally written in Python. A few years ago, I decided to try porting it to Go, mainly as a learning exercise. I created a new branch `go-port` that I used for this. Eventually this became the "main" branch: I deployed the app in Go from this branch, I developed new parts of the app in branches that I then merged to `go-port`, etc.

I have been increasingly annoyed that there's a `master` branch that has been untouched for years, and my main branch is called something else.

What's the best way to make `go-port` into the `master` branch? I don't want to merge them, as they are effectively two totally different apps. But I also don't want to lose the entire history of the master branch, which is of historical interest to me. What's the solution?

Comment: `git branch -m master old-master && git branch -m go-port master`?

Comment: That is a very simple and entirely perfect solution, which just never occurred to me. Thank you!